# 1D-Phase Unwrapping

Tags: phase, 1d

I am new to signal processing and I am reading about 1D phase unwrapping
[Here is the paper that I am reading.](https://www.ljmu.ac.uk/%7E/media/files/ljmu/about-us/faculties-and-schools/fet/geri/onedimensionalphaseunwrapping_finalpdf.pdf)

It refers to x as the signal but then it shows in the graph the axis are origina phase in radians againts sample index. So is x the signal or the phase function?
Also it says that signal x whose amplitude exceeds the range [-π,π].
All the above are for figures 1.
I am asking that, because I am confused on wether we compare phases or amplitudes.
So is x the phase of a function like sin(x)? I think whis sums up my question (page 1 of pdf)
I hope i didnt confuse anyone.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this not a particularly well written paper with confusing terminology and needless complications, so I recommend to look somewhere else.

> So is x the signal or the phase function?

It is the phase function. Choosing a sine wave as a phase function is certainly confusing, but it IS a phase function. "amplitude" here just refers to the magnitude of the phase.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand right, $x$ is the phase function thus a signal fas the form of $f(x) = \sin(x)$ which x is the phase function and can be whatever and $f(x)$ is the amplitude function.